# After upgrading to fedora 24, unable to login to graphical.target

Tags: fedora, upgrade, graphical-user-interface

I just recently upgraded to **Fedora 24**

When I start it it just gives me the **tty1** console without any **GUI**. I login as root and try:

```
$ systemctl isolate graphical.target
```

but it gives me the error:

```
 PolicyKit deamon disconnected from the bus.We are no longer a registered authentication agent
```

I also tried Ctrl+Alt+F7 but it was just black

I'd like to get the **GUI** back. What has messed up, and how do I fix it? Or what else could I try? Forgive me if I haven't explained well enough.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading a F23 system to F24 failed in this way and the fix was to:
dnf install sddm; systemctl enable sddm; systemctl start sddm
then reboot as described in http://osdir.com/ml/fedora-users/2016-06/msg00522.html

This system was originally installed as (I believe) F17 and upgraded several times, and only now in the F23->F24 upgrade hit the issue "Can not open font file True" described in https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=799401 -- I edited the files described therein, and also /etc/vconsole.conf.  In addition I rebuilt initramfs and re-ran grub2-mkconfig, and rebooted.

Both issues above are now fixed.